# AWS DynamoDB geospatial query using ElasticSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync

I am storing transactions tagged with geo-coordinates in a `DynamoDB` table. I want to do a geo-spatial query to find all transactions within e.g. 10 miles distance from an input pair of coordinates.

I saw [here](https://youtu.be/mQBtbHKSdAQ?t=1992) that I could perform such a geo-spatial query using AWS `ElasticSearch`. However, I am not sure if I want to pay the hourly fee for the service at this time if that is the only purpose I will use it for.

An alternative I thought of is to keep only 4 digits after the decimal point of each coordinate when storing and read all the transactions that have the same set of coordinates since they would essentially belong to the same like `100~200 m^2` range. This isn't a very good solution in terms of accuracy and range.

Any suggestion to a better alternative for such a geo-spatial query or on whether `ElasticSearch` would be a worthy investment based on time/cost?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using "Geo Library for Amazon DynamoDB". Features include Radius Queries: "Return all of the items that are within a given radius of a geo point."

It seems to have at least Java and JavaScript versions:
https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-geo
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-geo

Elasticsearch seems to support GeoHashing natively so it will probably have even better performance: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-geohashgrid-aggregation.html

Personally I would recommend using Elasticsearch for searching because it's extremely powerful at that and searching with DynamoDB can be difficult.

Comment: I took the Elasticsearch route and was able to load streaming data into Elasticsearch following this:     -  https://medium.com/@vladyslavhoncharenko/how-to-index-new-and-existing-amazon-dynamodb-content-with-amazon-elasticsearch-service-30c1bbc91365

Comment: However, I could not figure out how to convert content to geo_point or geohash so I still can't do geo queries. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the data type after the index field is created.   I used this code in kabana to declare the data type as "geo_point".  Then uploaded an item with the geopoint field and it worked.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html

```
 POST yourProjectName/_mappings/yourProjectType
{
  "properties":{
    "geopoint or whatever field you're storing the geo data": {
      "type": "geo_point"
      } 
    }
  }
}

POST _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "match":{
          "summary": "something"
        }
      },
      "filter" : {
          "geo_distance" : {
              "distance" : "12km",
              "geopoint" : "40.054447974637476,-82.92002800852062"

          }
      }
  }
}
}
```